# How to stub #sample with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I stub the return value for `Array#sample` in RSpec?

Given that the method I am testing contains the following line:

`["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"].sample`

I require something like the following line, which doesn't stub the behaviour.

`allow(Array).to receive(:sample) { "Rock" }`

Comment: I'd extract the `["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"].sample` part into a method and stub that method.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to stub such commonly used classes like Array.
You can get unpredictable consequences with other tests and code.
As Stefan suggested in his comment, you should extract `["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"].sample` into separate wrapper-method, and stub this method.

With such approach, you'll isolate this code in a safe way for stubbing.

Answer (score 0):

As Stanislav hinted at, if you stub a method, you need a handle on the object which receives the method.

In this case it is an *instance* of an array, not the *class* Array, that you want to stub on, for example:

```
class MyClass
  def pick_random(list)
    list.sample
  end
end
list = [1,2,3]
expect(list).to receive(:sample).and_return(1)
MyClass.new.pick_random(list)
```

You need to be diligent about the way you build your methods if you want to stub this way. For example if you decided to define the list inside the method, it would essentially be hidden from the outside and impossibly to stub directly:

```
class MyClass
  def pick_random
    [1,2,3].sample
  end
end

# This wouldn't work because even though they contain the same elements,
# the list here and in pick_random are different.
expect([1,2,3]).to receive(sample).and_return(1)
MyClass.new.pick_random
```

This approach is pretty standard for all sorts of mocking, but with randomness-based methods like `sample` you can also use [srand](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Random.html#method-c-srand).

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide the random variable to the sample method. By doing this you can make the test deterministic.

```rb
def sample(random = Random::DEFAULT)
  ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"].sample(random: random)
end

specify do
  expect(sample(Random.new(1))).to eq('Paper')
end
```

Passing a hardcoded random variable will always return the same element from the array. Depending on your OS and the Ruby's random number generator it can be a different element. For me it is "Paper".